# Cannot resolve exception error thrown for registration

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a registration right now, where if a user puts that they are under 18 years old - a error will come up after they submit their registration, saying `You must be at least 18 years of age.` but I keep getting this exception error thrown at the call stack in the submit table, saying the `string was not recognized as a valid`. I have put in `BirthDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` to attempt and fix the solution, but the error still comes up as a exception. Could I be missing something?

The error in question is

```
if (DateTime.Parse(BirthDate.Text).AddYears(18) > DateTime.Now) {
                errorList.Add("You must be at least 18 years of age.");
```

The code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace website {
    public partial class Register : Page {

        string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=HC;Trusted_Connection=True;";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

             BirthDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            if (!IsPostBack) {
                string QueryString = "select * from home";

                SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryString, myConnection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                myCommand.Fill(ds, "House");

            }
        }

        protected void submit(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            List<string> errorList = new List<string>();

            if (BirthDate.Text == "") {
                LiteralControl birthDate = new LiteralControl("Birth date is required!");
                BirthDateRequired.Controls.Add(birthDate);
                errorList.Add(birthDate.Text);
            }

            if (DateTime.Parse(BirthDate.Text).AddYears(18) > DateTime.Now) {
                errorList.Add("You must be at least 18 years of age.");
            }

            if (errorList.Count > 0) {
                foreach (string s in errorList)
                    ErrorList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("* " + s));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following overload of `ParseExact` method instead -

```
public static DateTime ParseExact(string s, string format, IFormatProvider? provider);
```

where you can pass your intended date format as a string to the second parameter.

So, if your `BirthDate.Text` is taking input in `dd/MM/yyyy` format, then change the code to -

```
if (DateTime.ParseExact(BirthDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).AddYears(18) > DateTime.Now)
{
    errorList.Add("You must be at least 18 years of age.");
}
```

Also, you don't need to set `BirthDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`